# aria-live element being read multiple in NVDA when using React

Tags: reactjs, wai-aria, nvda

Within my react application, I am noticing an issue in NVDA where my addition inside an `aria-live` element is being read out multiple times. I only notice this issue within react, and cannot reproduce it in plain JavaScript.

I broke down my code into the smallest reproducible item. With NVDA 2018.1 in the Firefox 59.0.3, you can see NVDA reads out the change 6 times, one per variable.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lx8jykqprz

When you press go, the expected behavior is that it should read the new counters out once. However, it is read out 6 times. If you change around the number of `${this.state.counter}` variables, you will see the number of times it is read out is changed.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, how did you work around it?

==============

**Edit**:
As I stated in my comment under the accepted answer:

What I noticed is that in my example, react was rendering 6 text nodes, one for each counter variable. This, in combination with the `aria-atomic` tag, was forcing the variables to be read multiple times.

By changing it to `${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}` this fixed the issue as it rendered down to a single text node, and therefore the change was only read out once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `aria-atomic=true` which says to read the entire block anytime anything changes.  The default value is `false` so it only reads just the text that changed.  When I run your example with `false`, it works ok.  When I run your original code on Internet Explorer, it works ok.  When I run your original on chrome (`aria-atomic=true`), it gets worse.  When viewing the speech viewer, here's what I see (and hear) on chrome:

```
000000 
000000 
100000 
100000 
100000 
110000 
110000 
110000 
111000 
111000 
111000 
111100 
111100 
111100 
111110 
111110 
111110 
111111
```

That might give you a better idea of what's being updated and read.  With live regions, the changes aren't merged together and announced once.  Every change you make will be queued up to speak.

If I change `aria-atomic` to `false` on chrome, I hear:

```
1
1 
1 
1
1 
1 
1
1 
1 
1
1 
1 
1
1 
1 
1
1 
1
```

In general, `aria-live` regions work pretty well.  I'm pretty sure you're hearing exactly what is being updated.

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track. For what I am doing, I needed `aria-atomic` to be true. What I noticed is that in my example, react was rendering 6 text nodes, one for each counter variable. 

By changing it to `\`${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}${this.state.counter}\`` this fixed the issue as it rendered down to a single text node, and therefore the change was only read out once.

Comment: glad it helped.  and i didn't mean to imply that `aria-atomic` shouldn't be used.  it's very handy for situations such as `<div aria-live='polite' aria-atomic='true'>you have <span>10</span> minutes left</div>` where the 10 is updated and you want the entire sentence read and not just the '10'.